# A string is not accepted correctly in asp.net action using GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, get, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to confirm Email using ASP.NET's Identity 2.0 system.

Everything works smoothly. I get the token (code) in Email and then I click it.

> ```
> http://www.mywebsite.com/Account/ConfirmEmail?Email=myemail@gmail.com&token=bkuVkQZUdEYrcrkcGWuzuPJsPt9cgk77oEZg5c4NVzfjye5THEtzQunBN7+/3SBOEbbmWD2K1loZfEUTh0ggm3qKuvKYGl9b0TWJBStHEeq8/G5RJ+dAvHh/fdt8Vtt5xyxHUgXMgT6+tDMox0Skfg==
> ```

However, when I receive the token in my Action, the plus signs are removed and replaced with spaces. And obviously the confirmation fails.

```
// GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string Email, string token)
{
    if (Email == null || token == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByEmail(Email);
    var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user.Id, token);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Confirmed", "Account");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

I receive this token:

> bkuVkQZUdEYrcrkcGWuzuPJsPt9cgk77oEZg5c4NVzfjye5THEtzQunBN7
>   /3SBOEbbmWD2K1loZfEUTh0ggm3qKuvKYGl9b0TWJBStHEeq8/G5RJ
>   dAvHh/fdt8Vtt5xyxHUgXMgT6 tDMox0Skfg==

What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: Try to "url encode" your token. you have some slashes that can mess up the parsing. Or you could use a custom model binder to read properly the token. Here is an article about model binders: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the token after generating it:

```
string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
code = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
```

this way all the special characters in your token will be interpreted correctly by all the browsers.

Comment: Some useful article: http://tech.trailmax.info/2015/05/asp-net-identity-invalid-token-for-password-reset-or-email-confirmation/